# OPC Server issue with loading XML page with LoadPredefinedNodes

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua, opc

I'm currently working on a C# project where I want to develop my own OPC server application that I can configure with XML. I already compiled a custom XML object with the UA-ModelCompiler [repo](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/tree/master/Tests/DemoModel).

I used the Boiler example from the [UA-.NETStandard-Samples](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples) repo. I added some custom objects for an agv and I want to integrate it with my own NodeManager. I copied the BoilerNodeManager and modified it for an agv. The following method always has an error.

```cs
protected override NodeStateCollection LoadPredefinedNodes(ISystemContext context)
{
    NodeStateCollection predefinedNodes = new NodeStateCollection();
    predefinedNodes.LoadFromBinaryResource(context, "Opc.Ua.Sample.Agv.Agv.PredefinedNodes.uanodes", this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly, true);

    return predefinedNodes;
}
```

With this error message:

[image: Dutch error message]

When I use the full path everything works, but with the embedded resource file it won't.

I think I forgot something, but I don’t now what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add the EmbeddedResouce path within Opc.Ua.Sample.csproj.

```xml
<ItemGroup
    <EmbeddedResource Include="TestData\TestData.PredefinedNodes.uanodes;MemoryBuffer\MemoryBuffer.PredefinedNodes.uanodes;Boiler\Boiler.PredefinedNodes.uanodes;Agv\Agv.PredefinedNodes.uanodes" />
</ItemGroup>
```